# WP7 check if internet is available

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

My app WP7 was not accepted because it fails to load if the internet is not available. I looked for a way to check it and found this command

`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()`

But it isn't working on the emulator and I do not have any device to test it.
Could someone tell me if it returns false if the device is in Airplane mode? If not, how can I check for it?

Thanks,
Oscar

Edit: I also tried with this code:

```
try
{
    wsClient.CurrenciesCompleted += new EventHandler<CurrencyConversion.CurrenciesCompletedEventArgs>(wsClient_CurrenciesCompleted);
    wsClient.CurrenciesAsync(null);
}
catch
{
     NetworkNotAvailable();
}
```

But I am not able to catch the exception, I also tried in the wsClient_CurrenciesCompleted method, but also no good.

Where could I test it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't test for "the internet in general" - test for the service you'll actually be connecting to. Test for it by trying to connect to it - make some simple, non-destructive request on start-up. Yes, that will take a tiny bit of the user's data allowance, but:

- You will be warming up the networking stack and making a connection which should end up being kept alive automatically, so future latency will be reduced.
- You could warn the user that they may have limited functionality if the connection fails.

Comment: That would be a great idea, but how could I do that? Because if I use the code I edited in the question, I am not able to catch the exception that is thrown :(
Where should I catch it?

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: @Oscar: Well you've said you want to do it asynchronously... so I'd expect the error to be reported in a different thread. Without knowing details about your client, it's impossible to say how you'd handle the error. I'd hope there'd be some way of registering an event handler for an error condition, or something like that.

Comment: Just found out: in silverlight you can check for the e.Error in the callback to handle the exception :)
tnks!

Comment: @Oscar where are you getting the `e.Error` from?

Comment: @Matt in my callback method (wsClient_CurrenciesCompleted), in the eventArgs. There is the Result property, which you can get the result and the Error, which stores an exception :)

Comment: @Oscar oh, your' using WebClient. I was looking at HttpWebRequest code  adn not seeing it. Thought I was missing something obvious. Doh!

Comment: @Matt I am developing for WP7, so silverlight ist the standard. Sorry, I didn't make it clear in the question: wsClient is a Client of my WS Reference :)

Answer (score 3):

An Alternative to Jon's suggestion is to check which network interface is available.  This is very handy in cases were you need to adjust which service you call based on network speed.  For example the switch statement below could be modified to return an Enum to represent the quality of the network.

```
public class NetworkMonitorClass 
{
   private Timer timer;
   private NetworkInterfaceType _currNetType = null; 
   private volatile bool _valueRetrieved = false;

   public NetworkMonitorClass()
   {
       //using a timer to poll the network type.
       timer = new Timer(new TimerCallBack((o)=>
       {
           //Copied comment from Microsoft Example:
           //  Checking the network type is not instantaneous
           //  so it is advised to always do it on a background thread.
           _currNetType = Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
           _valueRetrieved = true;
       }), null, 200, 3000); // update the network type every 3 seconds.
   }

   public NetworkInterfaceType CurrentNetworkType 
   { 
       get
       {  
           if(false == _valueRetrieved ) return NetworkInterfaceType.Unknown;  
           return _currNetType; 
       } 
       private set { ;} 
   }

   public bool isNetworkReady()
   {
       if(false == _valueRetrieved ) return false;

       switch (_currentNetworkType)
       {
          //Low speed networks
          case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma:
          case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm:
            return true;
          //High speed networks
          case NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211:
          case NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet:
            return true;
          //No Network
          case NetworkInterfaceType.None:
          default:
             return false;
      } 
   }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype(VS.92).aspx

Comment: Yes, I found this code and also found the one that uses GetIsNetworkAvailable. I have to say I didn't test the one you wrote because I am using an emulator, so I supposed that if GetIsNetworkAvailable didn't work, this would not work either. But this is a very nice code in case this "adaptation" is needed, tks!

Answer (score 2):

`GetIsNetworkAvailable()` will always return true in the emulator. For testing in the emulator you'll need to work round this in code.

This can be a useful quick check but you also (as Jon pointed out) need to handle the scenario of not being able to connect to your specific server.

Handling this can be done by catching the WebException when you try and get the response in the callback.

```
private static void DownloadInfoCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // This will cause an error if the request failed
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

        .....
    }
    catch (WebException exc)
    {
        // Handle error here
    }
}
```

Comment: And will it return false in the devices?

Comment: @Oscar Yes. Just verified on a device. Note that even in flight mode a device will still return true if connected to a PC though.

Comment: Ah, ok, but it returns true even if the PC has no connection? that is a little confusing to the developer, as if it worked only "sometimes", I think. Or did I got the idea of this method wrong?

Comment: Because the emulator runs as a virtual machine I would assume that it can always detect a connection to the host PC. The same for a tethered phone, as it always has a connection to the machine to which it is tethered.

Comment: The method is simply detecting ANY kind of usable network connection.

Answer (score 0):

GetIsNetworkAvailable() works properly on device.

You can mock your handling of this for testing in the emulator using Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType.

I would be inclined to test both for avaiability of the internet and availability of your site through exception handling and provide feedback to the user of the app that indicates what the true reason is for features being unavailable.