# How to Check internet is available or not in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

For internet checking i wrote the below lines of code.

```
bool isAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
             if (isAvailable == true)
             {
}
```

the above line always returning true if net is not available also.please tell me how to check the internet connection?

Comment: Have you only tested this on the emulator?  If so, see [here](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/11/16/WP7-Development-Tip-of-the-Day-Checking-for-an-internet-connection.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 check if internet is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378456/wp7-check-if-internet-is-available)

Answer (score 2):

> Check **NetworkInterfaceType**. If Internet is available then It
>   should be other than **None**

```
return (Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType 
!= Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.None);
```

**Reference Answer By [vjsrinath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069018/vjsrinath)**: **[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341169/how-to-check-internetconnection-in-wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341169/how-to-check-internetconnection-availability-in-wp7)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try,

```
bool isAvailable = Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable;
```

Comment: The above does not work when with a cellular connection. Only appears to work when connected to wifi.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Always check this in a thread, it takes some time        
    internal static bool IsNetworkAvailable()
    {
        bool _bhasNetworkConnection = false;
        try
        {
            _bhasNetworkConnection = (NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.None);
        }
        catch
        {
            _bhasNetworkConnection = false;
        }

        return _bhasNetworkConnection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking `NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType` in the UI thread is "dangerous" as it is a blocking call! It is possible that this call takes up to 20 seconds...

Use the following method to have a non-blocking call:

```
public static void IsConnected(Action<bool> completed)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        var type = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
        completed(type != NetworkInterfaceType.None);
    });
}
```

See https://xp-dev.com/svn/mytoolkit/MyToolkit.Wp8/Networking/NetworkState.cs (*From my project page*)

If you would like to change the UI in the `completed` action you have to run the logic in the UI thread. E.g.:

```
NetworkState.IsConnected(connected => {
    if (connected)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { 
            // TODO add your UI logic
        });
    }
});
```

If you need a lot of connection checks, check out the `NetworkStateTracker`, which is my project:

https://xp-dev.com/svn/mytoolkit/MyToolkit.Wp8/Networking/NetworkStateTracker.cs